# How to change Progress bar length in MUI instfiles page and arrange button position?

Tags: nsis

I'm using the MUI Page INSTFILES in my Installer and I want to change the length of the Progress bar and the Position of the "Show Details" Button in it.
Is this possible still using the MUI Page or do I have to make my own custom Page with `nsDialogs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to edit `${NSISDIR}\Contrib\UIs\modern.exe` and then use this new UI resource:

```
!define MUI_UI myNewUI.exe
!include MUI2.nsh
...
```

The other alternative is to call `SetWindowPos` or `MoveWindow` with the system plugin at run-time but this is a bit harder to do...